# How does armor segments work in Apex Legends?

Tags: apex-legends

When I read the amount of shields I got in Apex Legends, how can I figure out what is the 'effective HP' I currently got?

Like if a full life legend has 100 HP... how much does each segment of armor add to that pool of HP? Does one segment count as +25% max HP? +50%? Is there differences between a segment of blue armor vs a segment of purple armor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One segment of bodyshield is 25 hp. Everyone (as of season Legacy) drops with white bodyshields. This adds 50 HP. Each rarity of bodyshield adds one more segment of 25. The full breakdown is:

Base health: 100

white: +50

Blue: +75

Purple/Gold: +100

Red: +125

A bodyshield segment is the same 25 HP no matter what color the bodyshield is. A Gold bodyshield's segment only looks larger because it doesn't evo, so it is just stretched to cover the full UI of the health area.

Comment: Whether or not it's worth adding is up to you or OP, but worth mentioning that 1) it's referred to as 'shields' not more 'health', hence using shield cells to repair, and medkits to heal. 2) May be worth noting gold separate from purple as it doesn't evo like you said, and it provides bonuses to shielding/healing stims.